# Issue while converting an ArrayList into a bidimensional array, just last added value being showed

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have the following code:

```
ArrayList<String[]> pregsAl= new ArrayList<>();
    String[] row = new String[preguntasArray.length];
    for (int i=0; i<preguntasArray[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<preguntasArray.length; j++) {
            row[j]= preguntasArray[j][i];
            Log.d("row1values",row[0]);
        }
        pregsAl.add(i, row);
    }
    String[][] preguntasArrayrand= new String[pregsAl.get(0).length][pregsAl.size()];
    String[]row1;
    for (int i=0; i<pregsAl.size(); i++) {
        row1=pregsAl.get(i);
        Log.d("row1values",row1[0]);
        for(int j=0; j<row.length; j++){
            preguntasArrayrand[j][i]=row1[j];
        }
    }
```

When the first Log.d runs, I can see the correct values are being added to the ArrayList "pregsAl", however, when I use the get method to get the values into a String[] object **it will just read the last element I added into the pregsAl**  ArrayList over and over again (I can tell because of my Log.d). What I want to do is pass all the array preguntasArray to an ArrayList and then shuffle that ArrayList in order to convert that ArrayList into an array once again, however I cannot do that if I'm not capable of passing the array to an ArrayList and then back to an Array again successfully. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only instantiated one array, and you add that reference multiple times to your `List`. Move the array *declaration* and *initialization* to inside the loop. Something like,

```
// String[] row = new String[preguntasArray.length];
for (int i=0; i<preguntasArray[0].length; i++) {
    String[] row = new String[preguntasArray.length];
    for (int j=0; j<preguntasArray.length; j++) {
        row[j]= preguntasArray[j][i];
        Log.d("row1values",row[0]);
    }
    pregsAl.add(i, row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved it, does this have something to do with Strings being inmutable objects? why is the reason my array wont be updated every time it passes through the for loop?

Comment: @LuisE When you say `new String[]` that creates an array instance, when you say it outside the `for` loop; you're reusing **one** array (and modifying it each time).

Comment: (i have already marked your answer as accepted) But I still do not understand. Even if I instantiated that array before the "for" loop I am modifying it afterwards and adding the result of the modifyied array in the arraylist, why doesn't it work that way?

Comment: @LuisE There is only one array. You modify it, but there's only one. That's why only the "just last added value" is saved; when you call `List.add(Object)` it stores the `Object` that was passed - it doesn't create a copy of it.

Comment: Now I understand, in Spanish we call that "enlazado dinamico", I have totally forgotten about that, thank you for your great answer and patience.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[][] arr1 = {{"01","01"},{"10","11"},{"20","21"}};
    printArray(arr1);
    List<String[]> list = Arrays.asList(arr1);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    String[][] arr2 = list.toArray(new String[][]{{}});
    System.out.println();
    printArray(arr2);
}

public static void printArray(String[][] arr2D){
    for(String[] arr1D : arr2D){
        for(String s : arr1D){
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```